# PHPUnit not providing any output

Tags: symfony, phpunit, pear, ubuntu-13.10

phpunit used to work just fine, providing the number of assertions, errors...
But then i was trying to install skeleton generator for netbeans with pear, and things got messed up a bit (i had to install and remove many stuff).

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjDj7.png

CategoryControllerTest.php

```
<?php 
namespace Ens\JobeetBundle\Tests\Controller; 
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase; 
class CategoryControllerTest extends WebTestCase { 
    public function testShow() { 
           $client = static::createClient(); 
           $crawler = $client->request('GET','/category/index'); 
           $this->assertEquals('Ens\JobeetBundle\Controller\CategoryController::show',$clie‌​nt->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller')); 
           $this->assertTrue(200 === $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()); 
     } 
 }
```

php.ini error handling section:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
```

Comment: did you change anything in your `phpunit.xml.dist` ? What happens if you run `phpunit -c app` ?

Comment: try `phpunit --debug` and see where it is stopping

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan : i added the --debug option, it showed up this:
Starting test 'Ens\JobeetBundle\Tests\Controller\CategoryControllerTest::testShow'.

Comment: @nifr : phpunit -c app same output as before,and no,i didnt try to modify the xml file.

Comment: then there is a problem with CategoryControllerTest, can you paste it here!

Comment: <?php
namespace Ens\JobeetBundle\Tests\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class CategoryControllerTest extends WebTestCase {
    public function testShow() {
        $client = static::createClient();
        
        $crawler = $client->request('GET','/category/index');
        $this->assertEquals('Ens\JobeetBundle\Controller\CategoryController::show',$client->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller'));
        $this->assertTrue(200 === $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}

Comment: html <br/> not working,sorry for the not well presented code.

Comment: are you sure you have your error reporting enabled?!

Comment: how to do that?because i didn't alter any parameters.

Comment: check your php.ini file and see if display error is on or off, and if error reporting has a value of something like E_ALL or so

Comment: display_errors = On  i just changed it to on,restarted xampp and same output

Comment: @Shade - what about error_reporting

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan i provided the full error section in the edited post.

Comment: i found a phpunit installed in xampp, i exported the whole bin folder to path,with pear too, its working just fine now. thank you for your help :)